# Is it a good practice to use both Joi and express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express, joi, express-validator

express-validator does both input sanitation and object validation, whereas joi only does object validation. Joi is quite easy to use for validation, which I really like.

My question is, is it a good practice to use both of these modules? My gut says no and that I should just use express-validator as I'm using express w/Node.js.

I'd really like to get a community perspective on this.

Comment: well, I dont use express-validator at all, I validate all requests (body, params, query) only wiht Joi.

Comment: I'm using escape-html to sanitize the data though, before I even validate it. Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit opinion based.

While I don't use express-validator, I use `celebrate` which works similarly with `express-validator` but `celebrate` uses `Joi`, they both are validation middleware which validates data in controller level, if you have separate controller-service layer, I think it makes sense to use both `Joi` and `express-validator`, for example:

Your route (controller):

```js
app.post('/books', validate([...], async function (req, res) {
  try {
    await BookService.createBook(req.body);
    res.status(201).send();
  } catch (err) {
    
  }
})
```

and on your service file (BookService):

```js
function createBook(data) {
   if (!validateUsingJoi(req.body)) throw new Error();
   BookModel.create(data);
}
```

As you can see in my example code, I do 2 validation, first in router middleware (`validate[]`) and second on the service `validateUsingJoi()`.

I'd like to think that:

1. Router middleware validation (using `express-validator` / `celebrate`) is for specifying that "This endpoint requires / accepts x, y and z data in body / query"
2. Validation in service (using `Joi`) is for your business logic validation, for example book title requires more than 8 characters, etc.

But if you have proper validation in your service layer using Joi, router middleware validation shouldn't be necessary and probably redundant too, because whatever the data you pass to the endpoint, it should return the same results whether you have the router middleware validation or not.